# Getting different output from Math.Sqrt in C#

Tags: c#

I have interesting issue with Math.Sqrt in C#.
I am getting different output in one application (different place in application) from Math.Sqrt.

I have big project and application have lot of mathematics calculation.

Story

Animation Irrlich dll is use in the application 
Code:

```
private void Win_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
 double myOutput = Math.Sqrt(2.0); //1.4142135623730951
 IrrlichtCreationParameters creationParameter = new IrrlichtCreationParameters();
 creationParameter.DriverType = IrrlichtLime.Video.DriverType.Direct3D9;
 IrrlichtDevice.CreateDevice(creationParameter);
 myOutput = Math.Sqrt(2.0);//1.4142135381698608
}
```

I want to output 1.4142135623730951 every time.

Anyone have any idea, Why got different output after use IrrlichtLime.Video.DriverType.Direct3D9?

On which cases we got output different from Math.sqrt?

Comment: Can you show your exact code ?

Comment: Code  double myOutput = Math.Sqrt(2.0); Both place

Comment: Are you passing 2.0 as hard-coded ? or based on some calculations ?

Comment: For testing , I have passing 2.0 as hard-coded.

Comment: Question Updated........

Answer (score 7):

You have inconsistent usage of types (eventhough i don't see your code) but here is the proof :

```
double v1 = Math.Sqrt(2.0); // 1.4142135623730951
double v2 = (float)Math.Sqrt(2.0);  // 1.4142135381698608
```

You need to use the same type everywhere and do not do any casting or you might lose some precision.

It seems that you're doing a lot of calculations before you have the value 2.0 (it it maybe ≃ 2.0) . Double can't represent all numbers precisely, if you need precision then you have to use Decimal.

Comment: Yes, Got same output if i use like 
double v1 = (float)Math.Sqrt(2.0); On login page
double v2 = (float)Math.Sqrt(2.0); after login page
Output : 1.4142135381698608

But I want to output 1.4142135623730951 every time. Because i have use this values on pinv (MATHLAB) function (convert mathlab to C#).

IF i use this value 1.4142135623730951 then i can get mathlab algorithm output right.

Comment: @user2960398 please show the parts of your code where you're using `Math.Sqrt` and how you're passing it to MATHLAB. Edit your questions and show that information.

Comment: First I am playing with sample code like 

On Login Page

double myOutput = Math.Sqrt(2.0); //1.4142135623730951

On Application page

double myOutput = Math.Sqrt(2.0); //1.4142135381698608

Comment: Actually I used alglib library But getting different output.because I give wrong input. In my case, right input is 1.4142135623730951 but i am not getting this output from math.sqrt after application login.

Comment: After login in my application, every time MATH.sqrt give output in float type. I have not apply any conversation for float. if i try code like double myOutput = (double)Math.Sqrt(2.0); then also got output in float type. it should be in double like  1.4142135623730951

Comment: beta = -(mx * Math.Sqrt(AP.Math.Sqr(alpha / mx) + AP.Math.Sqr(xnorm / mx)));  All variable datatype is double

Comment: @user2960398 Please update your question and put this code with an example values for all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the 'wrong' result is, but be aware that mathematical operations like SQRT will always have some rounding error. That means that you should not directly compare doubles, but make sure they are close to within some tolerance;

```
const double delta = 0.00000001d;
bool same = Math.Abs(d1 - d2) < delta;
```

So if you get *nearly* the same answer, this is about the best you can get from double-precision numbers.

Comment: Both result are correct. But I want to this result 1.4142135623730951 (not 1.4142135381698608) in my case after IrrlichtDevice.CreateDevice(creationParameter);